# vertical scrollbar moving bit by bit depending on how far you scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on a scroll bar that will be vertical and as we scroll down the brown bit will not fill up but move bit by bit depending on how far we scroll down. So esentially the brown bit will move three times down if we scroll to the bottom. So far I made a scroll bar that fills up but ideally I would like it to have the movable brown bit like in the example in the attached picture. Anyone able to help out?
My code so far looks like this:

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-bar__inner")[0].style.height = scrolled + "%";
};
```

```css
.scroll-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 34px;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #959595;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-bar__inner:first-of-type {
  height: 20%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.scroll-bar__inner:nth-of-type(2) {
  /* height: 20%; */
  background: #ffffff;
}

#mock-content {
  width:  150px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-bar">
  <div class="scroll-bar__inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="mock-content">
  This div represents some content that causes the body to scroll.
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bit confusing what you were trying to do with your original CSS. I couldn't see why you would alter the height of the container for the scroll bar, instead of just repositioning the block within a full heigh container  (i.e. `.scroll-bar__inner`). In any case here is a snippet that I think accomplishes what you're trying to do:

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var containerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-bar")[0].clientHeight;

  // range from 0 to x% where x% is 100% - (80 / scroll bar height * 100)
  // This makes it so the bar doesn't extend off the page.
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * ((containerHeight - 80) / containerHeight) * 100;
  document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-bar__inner")[0].style.top = scrolled + '%';
};
```

```css
.scroll-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 34px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.scroll-bar__inner {
  height: 80px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
}

#mock-content {
  width:  150px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-bar">
  <div class="scroll-bar__inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="mock-content">
  This div represents some content that causes the body to scroll.
</div>
```